# A non-numeric value encountered in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Please help me to overcome this error. I am adding view and controller.

Error Message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: A non-numeric value encountered
>   Filename: company/job_responses.php
>   Line Number: 160

Controller:

```
public function JobResponses()
    {
        if ($this->Common_model->Is_Company_Logged()) 
        {
            $id=base64_decode($this->uri->segment(3));
            if($id && intval($id)>0)
            {
                $data=array();
                $sql_resp="SELECT u.*, i.industry_title, fa.farea_title, c.city_name, g.graduation_title, ja.jobapply_date
                FROM job_apply ja 
                inner join job j on j.job_id=ja.jobapply_jobid 
                inner join user u on ja.jobapply_userid=u.user_id 
                inner join industry i on i.industry_id=j.job_industry
                inner join functional_area fa on fa.farea_id=j.job_fun_area
                inner join city c on c.city_id=u.user_curnt_loc
                inner join graduation g on g.graduation_id=u.user_edu_grad
                where j.job_id=".$id;
                //echo $sql_resp="SELECT u.* FROM job_apply j inner join user u on j.jobapply_userid=u.user_id where j.jobapply_jobid=".$id;
                $data['rows']=$this->Common_model->get_data_by_query($sql_resp);

                $sql_job="SELECT job_title FROM job where job_id=".$id;
                $data['job']=$this->Common_model->get_data_by_query($sql_job);
                $this->load->view('company/header');
                $this->load->view('company/job_responses', $data);
                $this->load->view('company/footer');
            }
            else
            redirect('company/jobsposted');
        }
        else 
        {
            redirect('company/login');
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
              <p><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="margin-right: 10px;color: #00a2ff"></i><span><?php echo substr($row->user_email, 0, 8).str_repeat('*', strlen($row->user_email-8));?>***</span></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem arises because i changed php version 7.2.For temporary basis, basis i changed it php 7.0 to remove the error.